# Advice for addressbook server - LDAP, SyncML, CardDAV, or something else

Tags: sync, contacts, ldap

I'm looking for a solution to share a single address book across my Windows 7 laptop, Android phone and Ubuntu home server.  The address book should be synced to the phone so it is available when offline, and should be accessible to Mozilla ThunderBird on WIndows 7 and to a webmail app like Horde, Squirrel Mail or RoundCube.

I've tried setting up OwnCloud, CardDAV, Horde (with SyncML), etc and have not got anything working to my satisfaction.  Does anyone have experience doing this for personal use or a small organisation?

Comment: According to me carddav is the best option. Use [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution) to sync contacts among multiple devices.

Comment: I'm currently using OwnCloud.  The web interface for contacts is good enough and it supports CardDAV.  I am using the CardDAV plugin for RoundCube Webmailer (https://github.com/blind-coder/rcmcarddav) and the CardDAV-Sync app for Android (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.carddav.Sync).  It's good enough for me.

Comment: Glad that everything is working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me `CardDAV` is the best option. Its a open standard & integrated in most common webdav servers (Radical, Owncloud, etc).

### Clients/Plugins:

- `Windows7:` [Outlook-plugin](http://www.bynari.net/products-page/product-category/bynari-webdav-collaborator/), Carddavmate, [Thunderbird (Sogo-connector-plugin)](http://www.scalableogo.com/downloads/frontends)
- `Android:` [Carddav-Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.carddav.Sync&feature=related_apps), [Contact-Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vcard.android)
- `Roundcube Webmail:` [Roundcube CardDAV-Plugin](https://github.com/graviox/Roundcube-CardDAV)
- `Ubuntu`: [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/), Thunderbird, [Syncvolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution) (Sync EDS contacts with online services)